# Finding end of file in spreadsheets

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl

Is there an easy way to tell when youve reached the end of a spreadsheet file when working with openpyxl? Or does someone have an easy idea how to code this task in Python3? I'm working on a program that iterates through rows, selects & rewrites certain data. I want the program to be able to jump out of the loop on its own without having to input a number at the beginning.

Currently, I'm just using the following loop but it only works because I know the file ends at line 49:

```
while i <=50:
```

I was considering something that would check for several blank lines in a row, like this piece of code, to start the loop but it seems very imperfect:

```
while sheet["A"+str(i)].value!=0 and sheet["A"+str(i+1)].value!=0 and sheet["A"+str(i+2)].value!=0:
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

---

The easy answer is:

`lastrow=sheet.max_row`

The counter in the loop can then be set to terminate at `lastrow`.

Thanks for your input Roland.

Unfortunately the documentation for openpyxl I have been utilizing does not list this function, Charlie.

Comment: This is most definitely not the way to use the API. Please spend a little more time reading the openpyxl documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over a worksheet with the `openpyxl.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows()` or `openpyxl.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_columns()` methods.

Alternatively you could use the `openpyxl.worksheet.Worksheet.rows` or `openpyxl.worksheet.Worksheet.colums` properties. Those are iterators that are supposed to work over the whole file.

---

But for my own limited purposes of reading `xlsx` files, I tend to just open them as a `ZipFile` and grab the data that I want from the individual sheets using regular expressions. Works fine for me.

Below is an example. It extracts the hours worked on different projects from an xlsx-file containing timesheets for an entire year. For every sheet (that represents a single workday) I need to extract the project numbers and hours from a specific range of cells.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os.path
import re
import sys

__version__ = '1.1.0'


if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    binary = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
    print("{} ver. {}".format(binary, __version__), file=sys.stderr)
    print("Usage: {} [file ...]".format(binary), file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(0)
del sys.argv[0]  # delete the name of the script.
# Real work starts here.
projects = defaultdict(int)
wbre = re.compile('<sheet name="[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{1,2}-?[0-9]{1,2}'
                '".*?"rId([0-9]{1,3})"/>')
Anum = re.compile('<c r="A([0-9]{1,2})" s="[^"]+"><v>(.*?)</v></c>')
Astr = re.compile('<c r="A([0-9]{1,2})" s="[^"]+" t="s"><v>(.*?)</v></c>')
shre = re.compile('<t[^>]*>(.*?)</t>')
Fre = re.compile('<c r="F([0-9]{1,2})" s="[^"]+"><f.*?><v>(.*?)</v></c>')
for fn in sys.argv:
    z = ZipFile(fn)
    # Create a list of the shared strings.
    with z.open('xl/sharedStrings.xml') as sstr:
        ssdata = sstr.read().decode('utf-8')
    shstr = shre.findall(ssdata)
    # Create a list of worksheet numbers. The name of the workheets matches
    # NNNN-NN-NN where N is in 0--9.
    with z.open('xl/workbook.xml') as wb:
        wbdata = wb.read().decode('utf-8')
    matches = wbre.findall(wbdata)
    for shnum in matches:
        with z.open('xl/worksheets/sheet{}.xml'.format(shnum)) as ws:
            wsdata = ws.read().decode('utf-8')
        # Extract the data from column A, rows 4 - 22.
        A = {int(k): v for k, v in Anum.findall(wsdata) if 3 < int(k) < 23}
        As = {int(k): shstr[int(v)] for k, v in Astr.findall(wsdata)
            if 3 < int(k) < 23}
        A.update(As)
        # Extract the data from column F, rows 4 - 22.
        F = {int(k): float(v) for k, v in Fre.findall(wsdata)
            if 3 < int(k) < 23}
        idxA, idxF = set(A.keys()), set(F.keys())
        # Cross-reference project numbers and hours.
        for k in idxA & idxF:
            projects[A[k]] += F[k]
        for k in idxF - idxA:
            projects['geen'] += F[k]
    z.close()
    t = sorted([(k, v) for k, v in projects.items()], key=lambda x: x[1],
            reverse=True)
    total = sum(d[1] for d in t)
    for k, v in t:
        print('{:5}: {:.1f} uur ({:.1f}%)'.format(k, v, 100*v/total))
    print('totaal: {:.0f} uur'.format(sum(projects.values())))
```

To develop this code, I unzipped an xlsx file and listed the xml files in it with `xmllint --format` to make them human-readable.

Comment: Actually, this isn't working either. "iter_rows ()" requires the very same values I set in the simple counter. I'm trying to find a way the program can decide for itself what those values are. Also the way these spreadsheets I receive are formatted, I don't want to look at every row & incremeting the simple counter loop is letting me avoid the ones I don't want. So I'm really no closer to solving my problem than before.

Answer (score 0):

oneway to find end is to use dimension property:

```
import re
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def row_count(ws):
    return int(re.search('(\d+)$',ws.dimensions).group(1))

ws = load_workbook('your_spreadsheet.xlsx')
ws = ws.active
rows_num = row_count(ws)
```